# .htaccess rule almost works perfectly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess rule that selects the correct URL segments but is failing to rewrite the URL from this...

`https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/rss/templates/system/modules/note/themes/asset/static/js/geo/profile/static/js/jquery/rss/rss/blog/category/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/comment-blog`

To this...

`https://example.com/comment-blog`

So Removing these unwanted segments...

`index.php/module/action/param1/rss/templates/system/modules/note/themes/asset/static/js/geo/profile/static/js/jquery/rss/rss/blog/category/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/`

This is rule I am using...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:http(?:s|):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:.*?\..*?\/)(.*\/)(?=.*?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The regular expression is working as I hoped you can see so here https://regex101.com/r/ijoaK4/1 (thanks Robo Mop) but the rule is not writing the URL??? I have tried many variations and I have had no luck.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: _“The regular expression is working as I hoped”_ - that might be, but what you are applying it on, never matches that format to begin with. _“Is there something I'm missing?”_ - yes; what a _host name_ actually is. For the URL you have given, that is `example.com`, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: This matches no matter the host name I have tried the real host name and get the same result.

Comment: So you have still not gone and informed yourself, what a host name actually is then …? The host name of the example URL you have shown, is `example.com` - no more, no less. So your regular expression is not matching anything at all - https://regex101.com/r/ijoaK4/4

Comment: Yes of course I know what a host name is... I do not wish to revel the true host name here so switched it to example.com but if I change it to the real host name it still matches the `index.php/module/action/param1/rss/templates/system/modules/note/themes/asset/static/js/geo/profile/static/js/jquery/rss/rss/blog/category/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/` part in the URL

Comment: You still don’t get it? The _only_ thing `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains, is `example.com`. Your regular expression does not match on `example.com`

Comment: okay I think I understand now, sorry I have these rules now and it almost works

Comment: ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\^|~|`|<|>|,|%|\\|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)/ [NC]```

Comment: ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]```

Comment: But it fails in leaving the final segment (sorry about multi comments I cant get new line on a comment) Thank you for your patients